# Login System on WAMP

Tags: php, session

I transferred a bunch of website files that I used to run on a different website to WAMP, and it all worked fine, but now since I transferred it to WAMP, some of the login php stuff doesn't work at all. The `session_destroy()` stuff doesn't even work, I tried `session_unset()` too. Another thing I have trouble with on WAMP is `unset($_SESSION);`. It seems as if it's not even working. Any help would be nice.

Here is the logout script

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location:login.php');
?>
```

And here is part of the login script(The session register part)

```
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_start('myusername');
session_start('mypassword');
$_SESSION['F_name'] = $row['First Name'];
$_SESSION['L_name'] = $row['Last Name'];
$_SESSION['Email'] = $row['Email'];
$_SESSION['Password'] = $row['_password'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
```

I am confused on what to do. I have tried some things, and some things have somewhat worked, but all this code used to work on a different server, and it's all the same files and everything.

Comment: Where are the session files being saved?  Does apache have permissions to delete files from that folder?

Comment: check php configs on both systems. Might be some session configuration, might be some register_global issues. Just this info so far is not enough to get any glance of what you're experiencing.

Comment: I don't think `unset($_SESSION)` will ever work. You would want to use `unset($_SESSION['Password'])` to unset that from the $_SESSION variables. All the code you have presented looks correct. Have you reviewed your Error logs to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Is there a special place where they are saved? i thought they just got saved to cookies or something? Sorry im new to this.

Comment: If it's not working and you haven't touched anything since moving it, then you should also look at php.ini, httpd.conf etc as they function differently (including where session data is stored!)

Comment: And i tried unsetting the specific session like unset($_SESSION['Password']) But nothing much changed

Comment: More than likely, the php version on wamp is different than the one you were using before.

Comment: I checked the php.ini file and theres nothing i can see in the session part that catches my eye really about like deleting files and stuff, Is there any way i could update my code to work with wamp?

Comment: you'll want to see what is in php.ini for the session_save_path variable and check permissions on that directory.

Comment: It says this                                                        ; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.
;
; The path can be defined as:
;
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"                                      Im not sure what to change though

Comment: "I am confused on what to do" -- if that's *really* the contents of the login script, I can tell you exactly what you need to do.  Throw it into the *trash*.  [`session_start`](http://php.net/session_start) *doesn't take arguments*.  The code was surely converted from the PHP4-era, when you needed to call `session_register` and things were globals and ... eww.  I realize this might not be a *helpful* answer, but you really need to know that you're dealing with *crap* code here and not to get your hopes up on getting it running locally.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Yes my original code was getting a little crappy, so i went back to a default file, and the answer was pretty simple. I found that i just needed to call the session and then set variables like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION[SomeName'] = $SomeValue;
```

And When i wanted to check if it was set

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['SomeName'])){}
```

That Has worked out perfectly for me, Thanks Everyone for all the help too.